# How can I get data just for work days in Grafana

Tags: graphite, grafana

I use Grafana 3 with the table-extended plugin and want to get a time range of a traffic just for work days (except Saturday,Sunday). Is that possible?
The data are getting from the perfomance data of service which checks every 5 Minutes by icinga

Comment: I understand that the main problem is  a rendering from graphite. And all the manipulations connect with requests to graphite render.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible right now (v4.0.2 and back)